# Is markForCheck bad for performance with large components tree?

Tags: angular

For example I have big tree of components.

```
Comp1 > Comp2 > Comp3 > ... > Comp99 > Comp100
```

If in `Comp99` I use event binding

```
<Comp100 (event)="onEvent()"></Comp100>
```

or async pipe

```
<Comp100 [items]="$items | async"></Comp100>
```

`markForCheck` will be called internally. This means that **change detection** will be called for **each** component in a branch. Even if they have **OnPush** strategy. I suppose this is not ok for performance.

As for now I see following solutions:

Instead of event binding, pass functions (not valid for DOM events)

```
<Comp100 [onEvent]="onEvent"></Comp100>

onEvent() {}
```

Use custom directive to bind events and not call `markForCheck` inside of this directive

```
<div [appBind]="{'click': onClick, 'mousedown': onMouseDown}"></div>
```

Write custom async pipe but instead of `markForCheck` call, for example, `detectChanges`.

But there is such feeling that I'm missing something. What are common techniques of solving this performance issues?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular performance: change detection detached if component is out of viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248167/angular-performance-change-detection-detached-if-component-is-out-of-viewport)

Comment: your problem in this theoretical isn't your change detection, it's that your component tree is 100 components deep. Let angular do it's thing and rethink your architecture to be broader instead of deeper

Comment: @JoshuaChan, no, I'd like to know how to not call cd for all branch and use event bindings or async pipe

Comment: @bryan60, even if I got branch of 10 components, I don't want to check all branch on some event that fires often. Like text / selection change in text editor. Or popup move.

Comment: there are better solutions IMO. like debouncing events

Comment: Change Detection (CD) triggers when there are property changes in the data that you're using, and also if you are mutating the entire array of items. Technically, if you are using OnPush strategy, CD only triggers when the array reference changes. You can use trackBy to make sure your list doesn't re-render given the same value. CD isn't as computational intensive as renders. Pretty sure your performance issue isn't from CD. You can try disabling CD entirely and see if your app is performant.